# Redirection is not working after req.login using Passport JS

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

Below is Code Snippet :

When I login with correct Username and Password, redirection isn't working.
Can somebody please take a look in the code, if something I am missing out.
When I placed `console.log` inside `req.login function`, I found the console.log statement is printed and after that the '/login'(post) is called.

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
        if (err) return res.redirect('/');
        if (!user) {
            return res.redirect('/');
        }
        req.login(user, function(err) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            return res.redirect('/users/dashboard');
        });
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

Comment: you need apply a check on the '/' handler that if the request is authenticated then you need to send the dashboard page otherwise the login page is send

Comment: Still i am facing the same problem.